# Заполнение таблицы SQL

Tags: sql

никак не пойму, как разобрать следующий пример при заполнении таблицы: есть 10 работников, из которых один директор и один например тоже начальник какой. как мне поставить вот это условие на единицу, чтобы при заполнении только одна строка была с директором,один начальник, а 8-менеджеры?

```
set @s=RAND ()

BEGIN

if @s<=0.8 set @post='сотрудник'

else if @s>0.8 and @s<=0.9 set @post='начальник отдела'

else set @post= 'директор'

END

set @i=@i+1
```

Comment: А почему просто не завести сначала одного директора, потом одного начальника и в конце 8 менеджеров в цикле? И случайные числа не нужны :)

Comment: @VladD, можете чиркануть пример? :) я уже понял что можно и без вероятностей, но что-то не получается(

Comment: За час, который прошел с момента задания вопроса, можно было вручную заполнить 10 строк в таблице и покурить 2 раза. :-)

Comment: @wicS: если вы покажете, как добавлять элементы в вашу таблицу, можно попробовать.

Comment: @VladD,у меня таблица (id,name,post).как-то цикл в цикле должен быть?

Comment: Не могу понять в чем загвоздка? Сначала вставили одну запись с директором, следом за ней еще запись с начальником, а потом и всех сотрудников вставить селектом(если они в другой таблице) или написать 8 инсертов.

Comment: а зачем цикл в цикле? у вас там ещё id, вы его откуда брать должны?

    insert into ваша_таблица values (1, "Мбвана Пушкин", "директор")
    insert into ваша_таблица values (2, "Батоно Гоголь", "начальник отдела")
    insert into ваша_таблица values (3, "Парон Лермонтов", "сотрудник")
    insert into ваша_таблица values (4, "Херр Крылов", "сотрудник")
    insert into ваша_таблица values (5, "Насяльнике Блок", "сотрудник")
    insert into ваша_таблица values (6, "Масса Есенин", "сотрудник")
    insert into ваша_таблица values (7, "Властелин Евтушенко", "сотрудник")

ну и т. д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример судя по всему из какой-то статистики или теорвера)

На больших выборках (ну скажем пару сотен миллионов), я думаю вы получите свои проценты. О том, как добавить сюда insert-конструкцию - думаю знаете?

Ну что-то вроде

```
insert into table (id, name, post) values(null, @name, @post);
```

Естественно, тут нужно смотреть, откуда у вас проистекают данные - может быть ряд вариантов.

С точки зрения чистой статистики, есть ещё момент. RAND() насколько я помню дает диаппазон он 0 до 1(не включитая "1"), то условие должно быть
`@s>=0.8 and @s<0.9`, но это мелочи

Comment: @SilverIce: `id` = null? Хм.

Comment: Это с намеком на identity... В условиях отсутствия информации о структуре - почему бы и нет.

Comment: @SilverIce: это с намёком на primary key, по идее. Хотя ТС должен был бы предоставить больше информации.

Comment: В MSе насколько я помню автоикремент не по primary key и сделать нельзя... Хотя, конечно, могу ошибаться - я очень не люблю эту БД и лишний раз стараюсь не использовать.